# Why will spawning make a copy?

Tags: erlang

Whenever I use `spawn(Mod, Func, Arguments)` all the arguments are copied. Why are they copied if everything is immutable in Erlang? Why isn't just the pointer copied? Is it because that makes the garbage collection much more complicated?

Comment: Where do you see that all the arguments are copied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present, the Erlang VM maintains a [separate heap per process](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html)*. This means that a process can collect its garbage independently of others, making Erlang less vulnerable to the effects of GC pauses than runtimes that keep a global heap.

In order for this to be effective, it is imperative that no process references memory allocated on the heap of another process. *Presumably*, the reason for copying the arguments sent to `spawn/3` is so that they are moved into the newly spawned process' heap. The same holds for messages sent to a process, by the way (source: see the link above):

> All data in messages between Erlang processes is copied, with the exception of refc binaries on the same Erlang node.

(*) You might enjoy reading [this blog post](http://prog21.dadgum.com/16.html) about garbage collection in Erlang. It's actually a little more complicated than I said in the beginning as some objects (notably atoms and large binaries) are handled separately.

Robert Virding added the following in a comment below:

> Having separate heaps for each process make the GC simpler and more efficient, you can reclaim much more memory in each pass than with a real-time collector. Also it scales much better in a parallel system as there are much much fewer locks and less synchronisation, which kills speed. It can also give better locality of memory and cache performance. It's one of those things which sounds worse but ends up being better.

Comment: Having separate heaps for each process make the GC simpler and more efficient, you can reclaim much more memory in each pass than with a real-time collector. Also it scales much better in a parallel system as there are much much fewer locks and less synchronisation, which kills speed. It can also give better locality of memory and cache performance. It's one of those things which sounds worse but ends up being better.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Do you mind if I quote this in my answer?